# How to resolve a contextually bound class from Laravel IOC container

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection

I have a command class with a dependency type-hinted in the constructor:

```php
class RunAnalyticsCommand extends Command
{

    public function __construct(Analytics $analytics)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

The constructor for the `Analytics` class looks like this:

```php
class Analytics
{
    public function __construct(Odoo $odoo, ChannelInterface $channel)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

In a service provider, I've instructed the application what to instantiate for the `Odoo` class. If I create an instance of `Analytics` like this, it works fine. It gets the `Odoo` instance from the container and uses the `channel` that I pass in.

```php
$analytics = app(Analytics::class, ['channel' => new ChannelA]);
```

Now, I'm trying to use contextual binding to accomplish all of this "behind the scenes". I write the following in my service provider's `register` method:

```php
    $this->app->when(RunAnalyticsCommand::class)
        ->needs(Analytics::class)
        ->give(function () {
            return app(Analytics::class, ['channel' => new ChannelA]);
        });
```

However, now when I run the `RunAnalyticsCommand`, I get an error that `Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!`

I'm assuming this happens because the `give` callback is trying to resolve the same `Analytics` class, and the container treats that call as if it was *also* coming from the `RunAnalyticsCommand` class, so it just keeps trying to resolve the same thing over and over.

Is this the expected behavior or a bug with contextual binding? Shouldn't the call to resolve the class from within the `give` callback not behave as if it were originating from the `RunAnalyticsCommand`? Is there some other way to tell the container to resolve without using the contextual binding?

Comment: What happens if you replace the closure with a new Analytics object instead of using the helper app in there?

Comment: But then I will need to instantiate the `Odoo` dependency for `Analytics` myself, which is what I'm trying to avoid. I want the IOC container to inject the `Odoo` instance.

Comment: I got it, im trying to find out whether the loop originates from using the helepr inside the closure.

Comment: Also could you try to resolve the object and store it in a variable before making the call to ->when?

Comment: Got it. To your first question, if I create the `Analytics` object rather than using the `app` helper it works fine. To your second question, yes storing it in a variable first works, but that leads to the problem that it's always going to return the same instance. As soon as I do the resolving within the `give` callback, it fails.

Comment: Could you try the makeWith method? app()->makeWith(Analytics::class, ['channel' => new ChannelA]) or App::makeWith(Analytics::class, ['channel' => new ChannelA])

Comment: That doesn't change anything. Neither does using the `$app` variable in the `give` closure rather than the global `app` helper or the `App` facade. Nothing seems to make a difference. It treats the call as if it originates from the original class being resolved. I can't tell if this is intentional or not. I think it's a bug. I put it on Github but no response yet. If you have any other ideas I'm all ears! https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/29766

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm blank.

Comment: Does it happen as well if you replace the classes names with the FQDN of each class as string? eg: `App\Commands\RunAnalyticsCommand` instead of `RunAnalyticsCommand::class. Did you also try to contextual bind the analytics class as well?

Comment: Yes @mdexp it still happens using the FQDN. What do you mean by "contextual bind the analytics class as well". Where should I do that?

Comment: If you put as well: `$this->app->when(Analytics::class)->needs(ChannelInterface::class)->give(function(){ return new ChannelA; });` before the contextual bind for the command